# How to run asp.net core app in AKS with non-root user and listen to 80 & 443 ports?

Tags: docker, azure-aks

so, we have docker file with:

```
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
.
.
.
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' myuser
USER myuser
ENTRYPOINT ["dotner", "my.dll"]
```

This produces `Permission denied` in `Program.cs` when app starts and tries to bind to the ports.

Question is:
How to run the app that listens to 80/443 ports without non-root user?

Comment: why use those ports? your edge can map that in

Comment: @DanielA.White to be honest, i don't have a clue. This exceeds my skills related to it. I've got that code and I have to solve it. Is there any playbook what to do? (pardon my ignorance)

Comment: In your Dockerfile, add the following lines to set the user to a non-root user and change the ownership of the app files to that user:
`RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' myuser
USER myuser
RUN chown -R myuser /app`

Comment: In your Kubernetes deployment manifest, add the following lines to set the user to a non-root user and allow the container to listen to ports 80 and 443 as below

Comment: `spec:
  template:
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        runAsGroup: 1000
        fsGroup: 1000
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: myimage
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        - containerPort: 443`

Comment: Running your application as a non-root user enhances security. However, containers typically cannot bind directly to privileged ports (like 80 and 443) as a non-root user. To address this, you'll need the following strategy:

-   Deploy a Kubernetes Ingress controller (e.g., Nginx, Traefik) into your AKS cluster.
-   Create Ingress rules to map external traffic on ports 80 and 443 to your ASP.NET Core app's exposed port (e.g., 8080). The Ingress will handle external connections and forward traffic to your app.

Comment: Little bit explaination on this-   *Dockerfile and Deployment:*  The Dockerfile instructions and Kubernetes security context establish a secure environment where your application runs as a non-root user.
-   *Ingress Controller:*  The Ingress controller serves as a gateway listening on standard HTTP/HTTPS ports and redirects traffic to your container (which can now freely use a non-privileged port).

Comment: @Arko can you please write it as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run an ASP.NET Core app in AKS with a non-root user and listen to ports 80 and 443, you can use the following steps:

1. In your Dockerfile, add the following lines to set the user to a non-root user and change the ownership of the app files to that user:

```
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' myuser
USER myuser
RUN chown -R myuser /app
```

2. In your Kubernetes deployment manifest, add the following lines to set the user to a non-root user and allow the container to listen to ports 80 and 443:

```
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 1000
        runAsGroup: 1000
        fsGroup: 1000
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: myimage
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        - containerPort: 443
```

Note that you need to replace  `myuser`  with the name of the user you want to use and  `myimage`  with the name of your Docker image.

This should allow your ASP.NET Core app to run in AKS with a non-root user and listen to ports 80 and 443.

**Important Note:** Running your application as a non-root user enhances security. However, containers typically cannot bind directly to privileged ports (like 80 and 443) as a non-root user. To address this, you'll need the following strategy:

- Deploy a Kubernetes Ingress controller (e.g., Nginx, Traefik) into your AKS cluster.
  [image]
- Create Ingress rules to map external traffic on ports 80 and 443 to your ASP.NET Core app's exposed port (e.g., 8080). The Ingress will handle external connections and forward traffic to your app.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1 # API version for Ingress
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-aspnet-ingress  # Give your Ingress a name
  annotations: 
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx  # Assuming you're using an Nginx Ingress controller
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /  # Catch-all path to route traffic to your app 
        pathType: PrefixMatch  # Adjust path matching as needed
        backend:
          service: 
            name: my-aspnet-service  # Name of your ASP.NET Core app's Kubernetes service
            port:
              number: 8080  # Port your app is exposed on
```

**Explanation**

- *Dockerfile and Deployment:*  The Dockerfile instructions and Kubernetes security context establish a secure environment where your application runs as a non-root user.
- *Ingress Controller:*  The Ingress controller serves as a gateway listening on standard HTTP/HTTPS ports and redirects traffic to your container (which can now freely use a non-privileged port). This is standard practice for web applications in Kubernetes.

References:

- [Containerize a .NET Core App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick-start/building-sample-app#build-and-run-the-app)
- [Host ASP.NET Core on Linux with Nginx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-8.0)
- [Docker images for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/building-net-docker-images?view=aspnetcore-8.0#run-in-a-linux-container-or-windows-container)

Comment: Is there anything I need to do on the asp.net core application side? Make it listen to particular port(s)?

Comment: you might need to configure it to bind to these ports explicitly. By default, an ASP.NET Core application listens on port 5000 for HTTP and port 5001 for HTTPS. You can configure the Kestrel web server used by ASP.NET Core applications to listen on specific ports through the `appsettings.json` file, or programmatically in the `Program.cs` file.

Comment: yeah, that's what I thought. Man, I cannot thank you enough. Really, really appreciate it!

Comment: one quick follow up question: if we want to serve our application through https only (and we do), is there still a need to bind 80:8080 or should we go with 443:8443 only?

Comment: If you intend to serve your ASP.NET Core application over HTTPS only, and you are using Kubernetes Ingress to manage traffic, you have a couple of options on how to handle HTTP (port 80) traffic. Option 1 is to accept traffic on HTTP (port 80) and redirect it to HTTPS (port 443). To achieve this, you can use annotations in your Ingress resource to specify a redirect.

Comment: Option 2 If you decide not to accept any HTTP traffic at all and only want to serve content through HTTPS, you can configure your Ingress to expose only port 443 and not set up HTTP to HTTPS redirection. This means you would only need to map port 443 to your service port configured for HTTPS  (e.g., 8443).

Comment: would it be too much if i'd ask you to add that to your answer? So, a solution that works for both: http and https where http is redirected to https? thank you.